# Adobe Reader: Links to third party protocol not working

Tags: pdf

I have some PDF files with hyperlinks to a third-party protocol (ie. other than http://, https://, mailto:// and file://).

The links are on the form pw://xxxx.xxx.xxx

They open a document handling system on the client PC.

These worked fine in Reader version 9, but in versiosn X and XI I get a security block on them.

I have tried all security setting and trust manager settings, but nothing seems to address the problem.

Anybody got ideas or experience with this?

Regards
Leif

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Adobe staff say: "[Custom protocol handlers aren't supported by Adobe Reader X and later for security reasons.](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5593888#5593888)"